# Modify template of external app (django-moderation)

Tags: django, templates, django-admin

I'm actually working with **django-moderation** and **geodjango** at the same time.
The problem I have is:
The class "ModeratedObject" of django-moderation saves object's changes serialized.
One of my models has a "PolygonField" of geodjango, and when I enter to the admin site and want to edit some "ModeratedObject" instance, the admin.GeoModelAdmin from geodjango **don't render correctly the map**. And I get the plain text of Polygon Object.
I would like to modify the moderate_object.html template in my own project, to customise this functionality.
Can someone explain **where should I put** the moderate_object.html file in my directory tree in order to **replace** the django-moderation one?
Thanks!